# Indexing dataframes in R

Tags: r

good day 
I don´t understand a topic here, is like it works but I can´t understand why 
I have this database

[image]

```
# planets_df is pre-loaded in your workspace


# Use order() to create positions
positions <- order(planets_df$diameter)
positions
# Use positions to sort planets_df
planets_df[positions,]
```

I don´t understand why if u take the column diameter, then if u want to order it why u put it in a row of the dataframe like for me it should be [ rows, colum] but u put a column in a row and it changes, I really don´t get that.Why it´s not `planets_df[,positions]`.

The exercise is solved I just don´t get it, is a data camp exercise btw.

Sorry if my English is wrong, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that I have created an example that matches your description. For the `mtcars` data set, which is pre-loaded in any R session, we can sort based on the variable `mpg`.

The function `order` returns the row indices sorted by `mpg` in this case. The `ordering` variable indicates the order that the rows should be presented in by storing the row indices based on `mpg`.

```r
ordering <- order(mtcars$mpg)
```

This next step indicates that we want the rows of `mtcars` as specified by `ordering`. Essentially `ordering` is the order of the rows we want and so we pass that object to the row portion the call to `mtcars`.

```r
mtcars[ordering,]
```

If we instead passed `ordering` as the columns, we would be reordering the columns of `mtcars` instead of the rows.